# question about boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i have following code

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io,boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout<<" hello world\n";

    return 0;
}
```

but i have following error list

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/Boost'
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/boost
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/Boost'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/boost build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:205: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:206: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:211: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:212: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:213: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `error_code':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:312: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `~posix_thread':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:69: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::join()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:77: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `~posix_tss_ptr':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:61: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `posix_tss_ptr':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:47: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/boost] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/Boost'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/Boost'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 5s)
```

pleas  help what is happaned?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not in your code, the problem is in the settings of the compiler (actually linker). You need to link to the Boost.System and pthread libraries. Usually it's done by passing `-lboost_system`, `-lpthread` to the linker options in your Makefile, or favorite IDE.

Comment: i am using netbeans in ubuntu can you tell me how do it?please

Comment: Search in `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Libraries`

Comment: @Komel  i can't find configuration Properties sorry

Comment: please help    i can't find where i should link  Boost.system and BoostThread libraries

Comment: @algorithms, search around the menus. I neither have used nor have Netbeans installed, so I can't help you.

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz I don't think linking to Boost.Thread is necessary, Asio does not use Boost.Thread IIRC, but linking to pthread will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link with the Boost.System library: -lboost_system
Also you need to link with pthreads lib: -lpthread

Comment: sorry how? i dont understand like this?
 std namespace :: boost?

Comment: No, it's not something to be changed in code. The -lXXX flags need to be added to your makefile.

Comment: You need to find out how to link to 3rd party libraries in netbeans. I'm afraid I can't help you with that, as I have never worked with netbeans.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @algorithms you should accept it and ask a separate question specific to your IDE if you do not understand how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click your project root folder and select properties.

From there, you need to select 'Linker' in the left pane and the 'Libraries' option field is there. You need to browse your system till you find the libboost_system.a binary. Usually at /usr/local/lib.

If you cant find the file you are after you may not have compiled the source for those libraries yet. Check out either http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792 or the getting started documentation included in the boost tar package.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference to anyone with the same problem:
In netbeans right click the project -->Properties -> C++ Compiler and at the bottom there's an option for "Aditional arguments" pass in the -lboost_system option. Note: -lboost_system must be defined or you'll get errors